# PARTIAL SUM in table

Tags: t-sql

I have followed table:

```
2016-01       111.00       100.00
2016-01       111.00        11.00
2016-02       222.00       100.00
2016-02       222.00       100.00
2016-02       222.00        22.00
2016-01       333.00       200.00
2016-01       333.00       133.00
```

I need:

```
2016-01      444.00
2016-02      222.00
```

How I can receive this data? Sum by period, but only distinct value?

Comment: It looks like you are joining two tables to get this dataset?  If so, you could `SUM` the second column `GROUP`ed on the date value before joining to get the data in the third column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE `SUM()` WITH `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DateColName ,SUM(DISTINCT ColName)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY DateColName
```

Answer (score 1):

`SUM()` + `DISTINCT` + `GROUP BY` are your friends.

Recreate your test case:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE money(month TEXT, q1 FLOAT, q2 FLOAT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-01','111.00','100.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-01','111.00','11.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-02','222.00','100.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-02','222.00','100.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-02','222.00','22.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-01','333.00','200.00');
sqlite> INSERT INTO money VALUES('2016-01','333.00','133.00');
```

Check the data is same as yours:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM money;
2016-01|111.0|100.0
2016-01|111.0|11.0
2016-02|222.0|100.0
2016-02|222.0|100.0
2016-02|222.0|22.0
2016-01|333.0|200.0
2016-01|333.0|133.0
```

Run the query:

```
sqlite> SELECT month, SUM(DISTINCT q1) FROM money GROUP BY month;
2016-01|444.0
2016-02|222.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte
as
(select
date,col1,col2
,row_number() over (partition by date,col1 order by date) as rownum
)
select 
date,sum(col1)
from cte 
where rownum=1
group by date
```